# Illegal mix of collations when collation_connection does not match actual type

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

After upgrading from 8.0.26 to 8.0.30, I found a character set problem when calling the stored procedure.

When I call the stored procedure, the procedure returns a utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci string, which is then compared to the parameters I passed, and an error occurs.

If I execute `SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'`, then sql can be executed normally, but this only works for the current session. I've tried modifying `my.cnf`, `set global` and it doesn't work for new connections.

I tried changing my.cnf and restarting the database, then reconnecting with a non-root user and it still reports an error.

```ini
# my.cnf
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'
```

So, what should I do to fix this error without changing the client (which has to consider compatibility since it connects to more than just this database)?

| Variable_name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| collation_database | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |
| collation_server | utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |

```
create table test(
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(50)
) charset utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;

create
    definer = root@`%` function testCollate() returns varchar(50)
  READS SQL DATA 
BEGIN
  DECLARE ret varchar(50) DEFAULT '';
    SELECT test.name INTO ret from test limit 1;
  return ret;
END;
```

```
# collation_connection=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
# error
select testCollate() = ''
```

> ```
> Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,COERCIBLE) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
> ```

```
# collation_connection=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
# success
select testCollate() = '' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

```
SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci';
```

```
# collation_connection=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
# success
select testCollate() = ''
```

This online test address reproduces the problem: https://dbfiddle.uk/QsrN5pwE

Comment: *This online test address reproduces the problem* No, your fiddle is errorneous. Pay attention - your last 2 SELECT returns nothing whereas they must return `1`.. The source of the error is ```.. definer = root@`%` ..``` in the function definition.

Comment: *I've tried modifying my.cnf, set global and it doesn't work for new connections. ... what should I do to fix this error* You must find correct options file and edit it. And do not forget to restart MySQL service after options file edition.

Comment: @Akina As you said I changed the code for fiddle and updated it to the question, now the last two selects return 1 correctly, but the error reported in my question is unchanged.

Comment: What was the collation when the procedure was _created_?  Check `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE name` to see.